# Performance of batched statements using INSERT ... SET vs INSERT ... VALUES

Tags: mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I recently wrote a simple Java program that processed some data and inserted it in a MyISAM table. About 35000 rows had to be inserted. I wrote the INSERT statement using INSERT ... SET syntax and executed it for all rows with `PreparedStatement.executeBatch()`. So:

```java
String sql = "INSERT INTO my_table"
            + " SET "
                + " my_column_1 = ? "
                + " my_column_2 = ? "
                ... 
                + " my_column_n = ? ";
try(PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql)){
    for(Object o : someCollection){
        pst.setInt(1, ...);
        pst.setInt(2, ...);
        ...
        pst.setInt(n, ...);

        pst.addBatch();
    }
    pst.executeBatch();
}
```

I tried inserting all rows in a single batch and in bacthes of 1000, but in all cases the execution was VERY slow (about 1 minute per 1000 rows). After some tinkering I found that changing the syntax to INSERT ... VALUES improved the speed dramatically, 100x at the very least (I didn't measure it accurately).

```java
String sql = "INSERT INTO my_table (my_column_1, my_column_2, ... , my_column_n)"
            + " VALUES (?, ?, ... , ?)";
```

What's going on here? Can it be that the JDBC driver cannot rewrite the batches when using INSERT ... SET? I didn't find any documentation about this. I am creating my connections with options `rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useServerPrepStmts=false`.

I first noticed this problem when accessing a database in another host. That is, I have used the INSERT ... SET approach before without any noticeable performance issue in applications that were executing in the same host as the database. So I guess the problem may be that many more statements are sent over the network with INSERT ... SET than with INSERT ... VALUES.

Comment: `INSERT...SET` statement is non-standard SQL. Why are you using it?

Comment: @kums because I think that it's more readable and maintainable. In fact I'm using a little library that allows me to name the parameters and reference them by name, instead of using question marks and ordinal positions. With INSERT ... VALUES you have to write a list of parameters in the same order as the list of fields, which leads to poor readability as the number of fields increases. With INSERT ... SET I can neatly place every parameter next to its field. And RDBMS portability is not an issue in the projects I am working in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you examine the INSERT ... SET syntax, you'll see it's only meant for inserting a single row.  INSERT ... VALUES is meant for inserting multiple rows at one time.

In other words - even though you set rewriteBatchedStatements=true, the JDBC driver can't optimize the SET variation like it can with the VALUES variation because SET is not built for the batch case you have.  Use VALUES to compress N inserts into one.

<s>Bonus tip - If you use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the JDBC currently can't rewrite those statements either.</s> (edit: This statement is false - my mistake.)

There's an option you can set to verify all of this for yourself (I think it's 'profileSQL').

Comment: That makes sense. However it would be nice that the JDBC driver automatically changed the syntax to INSERT ... VALUES when necessary. That's what _rewrite_ means, after all. Is there any reason why this can't be done?

Comment: @abl Rewriting requires parsing of the statement, transforming insert...set to insert ..values requires more complex parsing, which is something you'd prefer to not do in the driver (I think the fact that MySQL is capable of rewriting hints at a missing feature in their protocol.